# Spring MVC проблема с валидацией

Tags: java, java-ee, spring, валидация, spring-mvc

Только начал изучать Spring дошел до валидации формы (Есть dao/service и весь стандартный набор)

Пытаюсь выполнить стандартную задачу по валидации что бы вписать в поле можно было только не больше 3 символов `@Size(min = 1, max = 3)`

после чего содержание формы передаются в бд и выводятся на главной НО
происходит слудующее... при отправки формы из 1-2-3 символов что удовлетворяет условие валидации форма отправляется все пишется в БД и выводится на главной
Но в ситуации когда условия не соблюдены и я предаю 4 или больше символов то я не вижу ошибок валидации но при этом в БД оно не пишет соответственно на главную записи не выводит и после отправки формы сразу падает по `HTTP Status 400 -` Кто просвистит неуча буду признателен.

```
@Controller
public class BookController {

    @Autowired
    private BookService bookService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "addBook", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String addUser(Model model) {

        model.addAttribute("user", new ValidationField());
        model.addAttribute("book", new Book());

        return "addBook";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "addBook", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addBook( @ModelAttribute("user") @Valid ValidationField validationField, Book book, BindingResult result) {
        /*this.user(book, result);*/

        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "addBook";
        }
        this.bookService.addBook(book);

        return "redirect:/";
    }
}
```

Класс валидации

```
public class ValidationField {

    @Size(min = 1, max = 3)
    private String name;

    @Size(min = 1, max = 3)
    private String genre;
}
```

и Вьюха addBook.jsp

```
<%@taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@taglib prefix="t" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" %>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<t:tamplate>
  <form:form method="post" action="addBook" commandName="book" modelAttribute="user">
      <form:errors path="*" cssClass="alert alert-danger" element="div" />
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><form:input path="name"/></td>
                <td><form:errors path="name"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><form:input path="genre" /></td>
                <td><form:errors path="genre"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"> <input type="submit" value="add book"> </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form:form>
</t:tamplate>
```

Answer (score 1):

Кому интересно то проблему решил тем что модель должна идти после BindingResult и нужно было просто поменять местами

Answer (score 0):

```
if (result.hasErrors()) {
    return "addBook";
}
```

Нужно перенаправлять так:

```
return "redirect:/addBook?errorStatus"
```

В jsp добавьте(нету блока отвечающего за вывод информации об ошибке, скорее всего):

```
<c:if test="${not empty errorStatus}">
        <h1>System Errors</h1>
</c:if>
```

Comment: Мб я не прав но блок для вывода ошибки есть в форме вот он


`<form:errors path="*" cssClass="alert alert-danger" element="div" />`
Но я сделал как вы и нечего не изменилось